# prefix symbol sequence in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols

I am trying to extend a symbol sequence with a prefix in lisp:

```
(A B C) => (pfx:A pfx:B pfx:C)
```

In order to do so I am trying the following:

```
(mapcar (lambda (arg) (concatenate 'pfx: arg) ) '(a b))
```

But to no avail.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Are you trying to use packages?

Comment: CONCATENATE does not work with symbols. It works with strings, though.

Comment: I am trying to get ox-taskjuggler working. There is a variable holding valid symbols for applicable org-mode symbols, but depending on your setup they need to be prefixed in order to export properly. Of course it is very nice, if this is done by function instead of explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a symbol in a package, use the [`INTERN`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/f_intern.htm#intern) function:

```
(mapcar (lambda (arg) (intern (symbol-name arg) 'pfx)) '(a b))
```

This assumes you've already created the `PFX` package.

Comment: Error: `a` is not a string.

Comment: Need to call `SYMBOL-NAME` to get the name of the symbol.

Comment: @Barmar, this works only partly: I need (pfx:A pfx:B) as output. The intern function will create with double colons: (pfx::A pfx::B).

Alternatively, (intern(concatenate 'string "pfx:" "A")) will create |pfx:A|.

Is there something which creates (pfx:A pfx:B)?

Comment: You would need to export the symbols for them to print with single colons.

Comment: The pipes aren't part of the symbol name. They're just used in the printed representation to indicate that the symbol contains special characters in the name.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to do this. If you want strings, use strings, not symbols.